# SQL query loads very slow from php but fast in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, sql, performance, phpmyadmin, return

I'm working on a School Management System App. The following query run very fast at phpmyadmin directly but returns very slow from php page. My SQL statement:

```
 SELECT stuinfo.stuid,
       stuclassinfo.ID,
       stuinfo.stuname,
       stuclassinfo.roll,
       stuclassinfo.Group,
       stuclassinfo.Section,
       stuclassinfo.FourthSub
  FROM stuclassinfo
 inner join stuinfo
    on stuclassinfo.stuid = stuinfo.stuid
 where stuinfo.InsID = '1001'
   and stuclassinfo.InsID = '1001'
   and stuclassinfo.ClassName = 'Nine'
   and stuclassinfo.Section = 'A'
   and stuclassinfo.Shift = 'Morning'
   and stuclassinfo.year = '2015'
   AND stuclassinfo.stuid NOT In
       (SELECT stuid
          FROM stuclassinfo
         where InsID = '1001'
           and Shift = 'Morning'
           and year = '2016'
           and ClassName = 'Ten')
 order by stuclassinfo.roll
```

But its return fast without following part of code "`AND stuclassinfo.stuid NOT In (SELECT stuid FROM stuclassinfo where InsID='1001' and Shift='Morning' and year='2016' and ClassName='Ten')"`

Any idea why such a difference ?

Comment: Hello Nuha -  Can you please try with `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`? As `LEFT JOIN` is faster than `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: :( No. its not working... anyway thanks Vikram

Comment: @Nuha in general IN is slower than, you should look at speed of this statement 'SELECT stuid FROM stuclassinfo where InsID='1001' and Shift='Morning' and year='2016' and ClassName='Ten''